# I have this annoying JUnit error. expected:<11> but was:<0>

Tags: junit

```
//A method for find the smallest integer from the array, assuming
//that the array is not empty

public class SmallestIntegerFinder {
    public static int findSmallestInt(int[] arrayOfIntegers) {
        int smallest=0;
        for(int i=0;i<arrayOfIntegers.length;i++){ 

            if(smallest>arrayOfIntegers[i]) {
                smallest=arrayOfIntegers[i];
            }

        }
        return smallest; 
    }
}


//Junit test
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class SmallestIntegerFinderTest {

    @Test
    public void example1(){
        int expected = 11;
        int actual = SmallestIntegerFinder.findSmallestInt(new int[]{78,56,232,12,11,43});
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

}
```

I have this annoying error. expected:<11> but was:<0> java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<11> but was:<0> what can I do? How do I sovle this error?? The code works well when i do not use JUnit. As soon as I include JUnit test I get errors. Please advise

Comment: 0 _is_ the smallest possible integer when compared with all the array entries. Your JUnit is fine. You need to initialize `smallest` to Integer.MAX_VALUE or something like that.

Comment: You seem to be assuming there's some sort of bug with JUnit. Don't you think it would be more likely there's a bug in your test?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that when you initialize `smallest`, you set it to 0, which is smaller than all of your test data, hence the 0 result.

A naive way of solving this would be to initially set `smallest` to some obscenely large constant, however this still may not work if you end up working with an even larger dataset. (Technically you could set it to the max integer value, but this is quite ugly)

A better solution would be to initialize the value of `smallest` to the first integer of your dataset, `arrayOfIntegers[0]`. By doing this, `smallest` is guaranteed to be at least as large as at least one item in your dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, i did set smallest to the first integer of my data set...and it worked efficiently.